# linux: how to capture the number/s from string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, perl

I use the following syntax in order to capture only the number from machine hostname

```
echo machineLinux05 | sed s'/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'

05
```

But this way is not so elegant. Is there another short alternative to capture the number from the string?

Comment: What is the purpose of `sed s'/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`?  In your example, neither of these commands does anything.

Comment: the purpose is in case hostname have also the domain name as machineLinux05.FG.com

Comment: `tr -cd '[0-9]' <<< "machineLinux05"`

Comment: `echo machineLinux05.FG,com | grep -o '[0-9]\+'` also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just get rid of the first `sed` and `awk`, they're pointless:

```
$ echo machineLinux05 | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

Comment: in case we have also the domain as machineLinux05.FG,com , then can you please update the answer

Comment: @enodmilvado This still prints 05 even with a fully qualified machine name

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one-liner:

```
echo machineLinux05.FG.com | perl -pe 's/\..*$//;s/[^0-9\n]+//g'
```

Comment: in case we have also the domain as machineLinux05.FG,com , then can you please update the answer

Comment: `s/\..*$//` removes first dot and all chars after it.